# How to include a packaged CSS resource in a Dart web app's minified CSS

Tags: sass, dart

I am trying to use a Dart package which contains only a single resource: a minified CSS asset: https://github.com/agilord/bulma_min.

The documentation just says I should put this package in my pubspec.yaml and everything will just work... but nothing works.

I guess I need to make the web_compilers build dependency minify my own CSS together with the CSS from this package, but I have not found documentation anywhere explaining how to do this.

I've tried using saas_builder but it does not seem to work with Dart 2.1... I've created [an issue](https://github.com/dart-league/sass_builder/issues/55) but nobody bothered to reply so far.

Can anyone tell me what is going on and how I can get this working?

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for a while, I found an example project using [dart_bulma_sass](https://github.com/indiealexh/dart_bulma_sass): https://github.com/indiealexh/dart_bulma_sass_example.

Even though it currently uses an old version which does not work with Dart 2.1, upgrading the dependencies makes it work!

Basically, my pubspec.yaml file just needed these dev deps:

```
dev_dependencies:
build_runner: ^1.1.2
bulma_sass: '>=0.7.1'
sass_builder: ^2.1.2
build_web_compilers: ^1.0.0
```

After that, added this to `web/main.scss`:

```
@import "package:bulma_sass/scss/bulma";
```

And linked to the generated css in the `web/index.html` file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
```